# How can I check the node of the selection using Range object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, range

I want to retireve the selection and check the node of the selection. I'm trying following code. But I think, I'm not able to point to the selection and so the code fails.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectAnchorNode () {
        if (window.getSelection) {        // Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari
            var selection = window.getSelection ();
            if (selection.anchorNode) {
                var rangeToSelect = document.createRange ();
                alert(selection.anchorNode.nodeName);

        } else {
            alert ("Your browser does not support this example!");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="SelectAnchorNode ();">Click to check!</button>
    <br /><br />
    <div>
        <div>This is the first line.</div>
        <p>This is the second line.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code, your missing a "}" to close the function.

Also this wont return true since the selection is made on a button and not on an anchor (link)

Try this code (I understand if this isn't what you want, but it makes your example work)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectAnchorNode () {
        if (window.getSelection) {        // Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            if (selection.anchorNode) {
                var rangeToSelect = document.createRange();
                alert(selection.anchorNode.nodeName);
            } else {
                alert ("Your browser does not support this example!");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a onclick="SelectAnchorNode();">Click to check!</a>
<br /><br />
<div>
    <div>This is the first line.</div>
    <p>This is the second line.</p>
</div>
```

As you can see I replaced "button" with "a", and added a missing "}"

EDIT!
Try this line instead, (I have now assumed that you want to get the selection made by the user, and that you don't want to create a selection with javascript?)

```
alert(selection.anchorNode.parentNode.nodeName);
```

Depending on where you start your selection you will get different results, you also need to first check if there was a text node selected or not (since I could make a selection directly in body). But I hope this brings you closer to your solution.

Regards
Tobias

Comment: Sorry for bugs..those were added at the time of editing...Also, I was able to display the output "#text", but I need to display the node of selection, that can  be either p or div based on selection. Thanks for quick reply.