# How can I tell the owner of a selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I tell who the parent node of a selection is?

I'm getting a selection with:

```
        var userSelection;
        if (window.getSelection) {
            userSelection = window.getSelection();
        }
        else if (document.selection) { 
            userSelection = document.selection.createRange();
        }

        var selectedText = userSelection;
        if (userSelection.text)
            selectedText = userSelection.text;
```

But how can i tell who's the parent node of the selection? That is, if the whole selection is from withing a single `div` I want to know that div.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check the node of the selection using Range object in javascript ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204822/how-can-i-check-the-node-of-the-selection-using-range-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will return the parent *element* of the selection in all major browsers, with the following caveats:

- Getting the parent *node* instead (which could be of any type but is most commonly a text node) is easy on most browsers but tricky in IE < 9. If you need to do this, there are libraries such as my own [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) that provide DOM Range and Selection support for all major browsers.
- The function below only considers the first Range within the selection. Firefox is the only major browser that supports multiple selections; only the first is considered.

Code:

```
function getSelectionContainerElement() {
    var container = null;
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            container = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
            if (container.nodeType != 1) {
                container = container.parentNode;
            }
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        container = document.selection.createRange().parentElement();
    }
    return container;
}
```

Comment: How bout for input fields?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(':contains(' + selectedText + ')').parent()`. Does that work?

Comment: True, but if all you have is the selected text, with no context, how else are you going to locate it on the page?